# How to type annotate a parent property/parameter in python without causing a circular dependency?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

Assuming I have two `.py` files

```
==== car.py ====
from .wheel import Wheel
class Car():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._wheel = Wheel(self, "large")


==== wheel.py ====
from .car import Car
class Wheel():
    def __init__(self, parent: Car, desc: str) -> None:
        self._car = parent
        self._desc = desc
```

wheel.py has a circular dependency problem because it imports car just for the typing, and car imports wheel for the actual instantiating. What is they way to type annotate `parent` property in Wheel class?

Comment: Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers. Despite possible technical solutions you should rethink your design. Currently you have a bidirectional relationship between the wheel and car. Think about if and why a wheel need to know its car?! A wheel doesn't need to know its car. You could come up with your real world example on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ maybe to discuss design decissons.

Comment: design is out of the scope of my question. There are enough cases where bidirectional relationship exist for a reason good enough for having a specific name for it. I just wanted to know how to type annotate without cyclical dependency issue. Just saw that the question is duplicated and the answer on the other topic is somewhat sufficient